# Multiple accounts question

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

Is it OK to use this account as my main stackexchange one, and one for worldbuilding (worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

I don't want it to get merged and I'm not going to use it to upvote on any other stackexchange sites; it's solely confined to worldbuilding.

The aim is not to use the accounts to boost points or game the system - but for separate interests' sake and because worldbuilding is not connected to my main usage of stackexchange (programming/travel/finances etc).

Basically, is it OK to have one account specifically for "day-to-day" stackexchange use (stackoverflow, programming, etc.) and one for worldbuilding etc. (worldbuilding, sci-fi).

I currently use this account on stackoverflow, stackexchange, serverfault, askdifferent, graphicdesign.

I'm only asking to check this is legit and to ensure I'm using multiple accounts ethically - two, in this case.

Answer (score 16):

### Yes.

The normal restrictions on multiple accounts apply. You are allowed to have multiple accounts, *but*:

- there is no official support for that; it's down to you to ensure they're separated enough to not get merged
- if you're doing something with one that you would be prevented from doing with the other (evading question blocks/suspensions, voting on your own posts), that's abuse and your accounts are liable to moderator deletion/suspension

You can also hide communities from your profile. Go to Edit Profile and Settings from your profile, and look for Hide Communities. The hidden communities don't show up for anyone except yourself and moderators.

Comment: Thank you. I did have older accounts before this one (lost password to both of them ages ago) - these need merging:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440736/json-with-php-page-of-mine and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128354/how-to-store-day-and-time-in-database-for-online-radio-station-project which should be merged with this account per your policy.

Comment: We were typing the same answer, so I deleted mine. Side note on hiding communities: it is quite easy to link those accounts, so no real security there.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How so? It's not, any more. The network profile doesn't show them apart from to mods.

Comment: @avenas8808 To merge accounts, you'll need to contact the team. Click on the "contact us" link in the footer.

Comment: If you share the display name Google will pretty easy find you. Also I think that SEDE can find those accounts too.

Comment: @Art finding other sites is still easy via the actions tab in network profile. It would still show actions on hidden sites, and the team has no intention to "fix" this as Jon confirmed to me a while ago. (I can find the comment if you want)