# There are [multiple] problems with this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple) tag has 11 questions about ... multiple ... different things: e.g. multiple accounts, multiple tags, multiple duplicates. It doesn't have an excerpt, and can probably never be used as the only tag on a question. Should we burninate it?

Comment: Yes. Way too ambiguous and no exact meaning towards a question. It's pointless! Let's burninate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple) is no more.

It was great to see some old and valueless closed posts were deleted during the burnination, as well as some duplicate closure. As always, the work put in by the [multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple) users who helped is appreciated!

[image: Burninated picture]

Comment: Blast, you type quick!

Comment: Accept (just one, not multiple) incoming when the daily job gets rid of the tag.

Comment: @Ollie I removed it from 6 posts over the course of the last week or so (one per day, typically). Of course I'm gonna quick to post the dragon! :)

Comment: @Spevacus yeah, I only did one or two, and I did get the last one... ;)

Comment: @Ollie [Did you, though?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/70341/revisions) :)

Comment: OK, maybe one...

Comment: @Spevacus Re: that last question: In the answer, there was one tag combination (of four tags) and when you clicked on it, it searched MSE for that tag combination, and the one result that appeared was the question itself. Now, nothing shows up because [multiple] was removed from the question. My thought was maybe to add a different tag to the question and edit the answer to again find that question.

Comment: @ThomasF I've edited the answer so it will correctly search for that question again. I don't know of a suitable additional tag for the question, but I'll try to come up with one in a little while.

Answer (score 13):

I say yes, let's burn it.  I had a look at the questions tagged with [multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple), and there were plenty that could've done without it.  [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277434/multiple-accounts-question), which seems like a good for instance, already had the [multiple-accounts](/questions/tagged/multiple-accounts) tag, and was tagged with the amibiguous [multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple) tag anyway (I have since removed it).

So yes, I think we should condemn this tag to the burnination furnace.